# Auto Layout Constraints not Working in Auto Layout Universal App

Tags: xcode, autolayout

So I've been making a app for iPad, iPhone, and iPod Touch, and I've been using auto layout and size classes to do it. But when I add the constraints it is somewhat miss aligned on some devices. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are adding your constraints in the universal storyboard:
[image]

What I would do is for example if your having trouble with iPhone Portrait click the bottom bar that says wAny hAny and change it to wCompact hRegular or what ever orientation your having trouble in then clear all constraints and then click the button in the bottom right hand corner and click 'add missing constraints' what this does is when you do that it only edits the constraints for the orientation you chose where as when its on wAny hAny it is for all orientations and can get mixed up sometimes.